# C pthread accessing an array from multiple threads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a problem for accessing an array from several threads. I have written a `struct` which gathers all informations needed for the job I want to do.

The structure is defined like this:

```
struct thread_blk
{
    size_t              th_blk_count;
    size_t              th_blk_size;
    size_t              th_blk_current;
    size_t*             th_blk_i_start;
    void*               data;
    pthread_t*          th_id;
    ThreadBlockAdaptive th_blk_adapt;
};
```

The idea is to fill an array from multiple threads, each one working on a delimited field of memory of an array.

- The `th_blk_count` field represents the amount of block that has to
  be treated,
- The `th_blk_size` field represents the size of a block,
- The `th_blk_current` field represents the processed block (they are
  listed from `0` to `n`),
- The `th_blk_i_start` is an array which contains indexes of the array
  that has to be filled.

Just a single function applied to the `thread_blk` `struct` is not working properly:

```
int startAllThreadBlock(struct thread_blk* th_blk, worker_func f)
{
    int res = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < th_blk->th_blk_count; ++i)
    {
        res |= pthread_create(th_blk->th_id + i, NULL, f, th_blk);
        th_blk->th_blk_current++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

In fact, the `th_blk_current` field is not incremented properly. I used it to retrieve the `th_blk_i_start` indexes which serve as intervals. As a result, my worker (shown bellow) is processing the same indexes of the `double` array.

Here is the function I use in the `startAllThreadBlock` function:

```
void* parallel_for(void* th_blk_void)
{
    ThreadBlock th_blk = (ThreadBlock)th_blk_void;
    size_t i =  getThreadBlockStartIndex(th_blk, getThreadBlockCurrentIndex(th_blk));

    printf(
        "Running thread %p\n"
        "  -Start index %zu\n\n",
        pthread_self(),
        i
    );

    if(getThreadBlockCurrentIndex(th_blk) == (getThreadBlockCount(th_blk) - 1))
    {
        for(; i < MAX; ++i)
        {
            result[i] = tan(atan((double)i));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        size_t threshold = getThreadBlockStartIndex(th_blk, getThreadBlockCurrentIndex(th_blk) + 1); 

        for(; i < threshold; ++i)
        {
            result[i] = tan(atan((double)i));
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

ThreadBlock is just a typedef over a `thread_blk*`; `result` is the array of `double`.

I am pretty sure that the problem lies around the `startAllThreadBlock` (if I use a 1 second `sleep` everything run as expected). But I don't know how to fix it.

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks for your answers.

### Update

Placing the incrementation in the worker solved the problem. But I think it is not safe though, for the reason *Some programmer dude* mentioned.

```
void* parallel_for(void* th_blk_void)
{
    ThreadBlock th_blk = (ThreadBlock)th_blk_void;

    size_t i = getThreadBlockStartIndex(th_blk, getThreadBlockCurrentIndex(th_blk));
    size_t n;

    if(getThreadBlockCurrentIndex(th_blk) == (getThreadBlockCount(th_blk) - 1))
    {
        n = MAX;
    }
    else
    {
        n = getThreadBlockStartIndex(th_blk, getThreadBlockCurrentIndex(th_blk) + 1);
    }

    incThreadBlockCurrent(th_blk);

    printf(
        "Running thread %p\n"
        "  -Start index %zu\n\n",
        pthread_self(),
        i
    );

    for(; i < n; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = tan(atan((double)i));
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

It would do it with a mutex on `th_blk_current` no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you think the thread gets passed a *copy* of the structure. It doesn't, it gets a pointer. All the threads get a pointer to the *same* structure. So any changes to the structure will affect all threads.

You need to come up with a way to pass individual data to the individual threads. For example a thread-specific structure containing only the thread-specific data, and you dynamically allocate an instance of that structure to pass to the thread.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you think the thread gets passed a copy of the structure. No, I know that it is not a copy. But I didn't figured it out. Tired .... Thanks